# Can you embed a unity application inside an android/ios app?

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine

I want to make a mobile app, something like a food ordering app with a game inside. So whenever user ordered a meal there, there would be a button to open the unity game embedded inside without opening a new separate application for the game. Can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do this , here is the official repo on how to use unity as a library for android and ios native builds . https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/uaal-example .

Comment: But this requires for me to write unity inside android studio for example? Or can I just call a unity build/apk?

Comment: You write the same as you always do in Unity, then build the project as iOS or Android target. If you want changes on the unity part you have to build it again.

Comment: you can directly call the unity view without writing any unity in android . Although you can send messaged to an from unity to android app.